# MVC4 publishing website on Arvixe giving error

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have published the website on Arvixe system pointing to MySQL database.
When i try to access the website, its working fine, but somehow after some page accessing, it start giving the error as:

> Server Error in '/' Application. A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
>   - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have pointed my website to MySQL database, but it is giving the error of SQl server.
For a check, when i run the website pointing to arxixe database from my local machine, its working absolutely perfect.

I have hosted the MySQL database onto Arvixe server itself.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Arvixe Hosting is very very very a horrible and irresponsible company, it;s only money trap. They squeeze money. my advice is change hosting company as soon as posible

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check 2 things:

1.You are using "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" in the connection string for the script on the server. 
2.There may be another connection string in the code, that is connecting to the MSSQL server.

There is a 3rd option:

Contact Arvixe's support as they will have exact details of what would be happening.

Good luck!

Comment: I have tried with both the options i.e. from localhost and from 127.0.0.1, but no joy. I am still getting the same error as defined above..

Comment: I have checked whole of my code, but i didn't find any connection string pointing to MSSQL server. If that would be the case, then login should also be failed.